# Why parseFloat() in js rounding the number if the value is above 14 digit in real part

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

For example,
**var a = parseFloat("123456789012345678.778")** gives the output as **123456789012345680**

Comment: This is Interesting also for me. Maybe this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat converts BigInt syntax to Numbers, losing precision. This happens because the trailing n character is discarded.

You can read more at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat